# DXL showing output but not reflecting in column

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using this script to get inlink modules info the script is working fine but its displaying output only in dxl window I want it also to reflect in a column when added as a attribute dxl can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

```
Object o = current

string srcModName
for srcModName in each (o<-"*") do print srcModName "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` goes to the DXL window. `display` is for DXL Layout columns.
In DXL Layout columns there is a predefined variable `obj` which points to the object which is currently being calculated. This is **not** the current object, which is the one that the user has clicked on.

Create a DXL Layout column with the following code

```
string srcModName
for srcModName in each (obj<-"*") do display srcModName "\n"
```

Edit: code for a DXL attribute would be different. For this you would use `obj.attrDXLName = "value"`